# How to triggger two select with on change with if condition on value

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, jquery-plugins

I am trying to trigger two select of woocommerce variations and based on the values ​​apply an inline style, my script is this but I am doing something wrong. Thanks

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    
var isDesktop = window.matchMedia("only screen and (min-width: 760px)");
    
    if (isDesktop.matches) {

    jQuery('select#pa_modalita-pagamento , select#pa_partecipanti').on('change', function() {

        var val = jQuery(this).val();

            if (val ==='acconto-saldo', val === 'partecipanti-1'){ // i think the problem is here

                    setTimeout(function(){ jQuery(".woocommerce-variation-description").transition({ x: '0px', y: '80px' }); }, 100);

            }

            else if(val === '') {

            }
            
            else {

            } 

    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The script works fine up until `(val ==='acconto-saldo', val === 'partecipanti-1')`. Instead of a comma, use the JavaScript or operator `||`. E.g: `(val ==='acconto-saldo' || val === 'partecipanti-1')`

Heres a basic demo: https://jsfiddle.net/emaozqjw/

A more elegant way of coding it, is to create an array of values and use the `includes` method to see if value exists. E.g `['acconto-saldo', 'partecipanti-1'].includes(val)`.

Heres another basic demo: https://jsfiddle.net/emaozqjw/1/

Comment: Hi @Greg.

Ok with || it works, but there is another problem, it only works if I select the first select and then the second and then reselect the first select changing the value, ideas? Thanks

Comment: In a HTML page works fine, so I Think the problem is wp_enqueue_script priority or some JS conflict, I need to debug it.

Comment: Hi, the OR operator does not work after the AND.
The logic I need is:

If the first select (# pa_modalita-pagamento) has the value "account-saldo" and the second select (#pa_participanti) have the value "participante-1" or "participanti-2" or "participanti-3", and so on I do stuff.

Then If the first select (# pa_modalita-pagamento) has the value "tre-rate" and the second select (#pa_participanti) have the value "participante-1" or "participanti-2" or "participanti-3", and so on I do stuff, ect, ect

the complete code on [link](https://jsfiddle.net/alessioangeloro/bf9gsL20/1/)

Comment: The comment above should be a separate question. Can you please create a new question?

Comment: ok, please follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69637141/how-to-use-and-and-or-operator-in-js-with-browser-detection Thanks.