# How to use AND and OR operator in JS with browser detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

the OR operator does not work after the AND. The logic I need is: If the first select (# pa_modalita-pagamento) has the value "account-saldo" and the second select (#pa_participanti) have the value "participante-1" or "participanti-2" or "participanti-3", and so on I do stuff. Then If the first select (# pa_modalita-pagamento) has the value "tre-rate" and the second select (#pa_participanti) have the value "participante-1" or "participanti-2" or "participanti-3", and so on I do stuff, ect, ect.
And than I must excute different code for different browser. The complete code on https://jsfiddle.net/alessioangeloro/bf9gsL20/4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
<script>
//browser detection
var browser = (function() {
    var test = function(regexp) {return regexp.test(window.navigator.userAgent)}
    switch (true) {
        case test(/edg/i): return "Microsoft Edge";
        case test(/trident/i): return "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
        case test(/firefox|fxios/i): return "Mozilla Firefox";
        case test(/opr\//i): return "Opera";
        case test(/ucbrowser/i): return "UC Browser";
        case test(/samsungbrowser/i): return "Samsung Browser";
        case test(/chrome|chromium|crios/i): return "Google Chrome";
        case test(/safari/i): return "Apple Safari";
        default: return "Other";
    }
})();

//if (browser == 'Mozilla Firefox' ){alert('CIAO')} 


//alert(browser)


jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    
var isDesktop = window.matchMedia("only screen and (min-width: 760px)");
    
    if (isDesktop.matches) {

    jQuery('select#pa_modalita-pagamento , select#pa_partecipanti').on('change', function() {

        var val = jQuery(this).val();

            if (browser ==='Mozilla Firefox' && val ==='acconto-saldo' || val === 'partecipanti-1' || val === 'partecipanti-2' || val === 'partecipanti-3' || val === 'partecipanti-4' || val === 'partecipanti-5'){ // not detect the browser

                    setTimeout(function(){ jQuery(".woocommerce-variation-description").transition({ x: '0px', y: '5px' }); }, 100);
            }
            
            else if (val ==='tre-rate' || val === 'partecipanti-1' || val === 'partecipanti-2' || val === 'partecipanti-3' || val === 'partecipanti-4' || val === 'partecipanti-5'){

                    setTimeout(function(){ jQuery(".woocommerce-variation-description").transition({ x: '0px', y: '5px' }); }, 100);
            }
            
            else if (val ==='unica-soluzione' || val === 'partecipanti-1' || val === 'partecipanti-2' || val === 'partecipanti-3' || val === 'partecipanti-4' || val === 'partecipanti-5'){

                    setTimeout(function(){ jQuery(".woocommerce-variation-description").transition({ x: '0px', y: '5px' }); }, 100);
            }

    });
}
});
</script>
<script>

</script>
</head>
<body>


<div style="margin-top:10rem;">

<div class="woocommerce-variation-description">

<select id="pa_modalita-pagamento">
    <option value="">Scegli un'opzione</option>
    <option value="acconto-saldo">Acconto + saldo</option>
    <option value="tre-rate">Tre rate</option>
    <option value="unica-soluzione">Unica soluzione</option>
</select>

<select id="pa_partecipanti">
<option value="">Scegli un'opzione</option>
    <option value="partecipanti-1">1 partecipante</option>
    <option value="partecipanti-2">2 partecipanti</option>
    <option value="partecipanti-3">3 partecipanti</option>
    <option value="partecipanti-4">4 partecipanti</option>
    <option value="partecipanti-5">5 partecipanti</option>
</select>


</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question has to be asked here - why are you performing any browser detection at all? There's no real need for it any more in the vast majority of cases. Feature detection/graceful degradation are better approaches if you cannot reliably create the necessary functionality for all required browsers.

Comment: Hi Rory, due to CSS and JS conflict on the web site that use Elementor and a lot of variety add ons, I prefer to detect browser and than ad a CSS inline to the div.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parenthesis if you use AND and OR in the same condition.

```
if (browser ==='Mozilla Firefox' && (val ==='acconto-saldo' || val === 'partecipanti-1' || val === 'partecipanti-2' || val === 'partecipanti-3' || val === 'partecipanti-4' || val === 'partecipanti-5'))
```

By the way, you could add all your accepted values into an array and make the if shorter

```
let participanti = ['partecipanti-1','partecipanti-2','partecipanti-3','partecipanti-4','partecipanti-5'];

if (if (browser ==='Mozilla Firefox' && participanti.includes(val)) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @Balastrong this code not working, runs even if the browser is Opera; any idea ?

if (browser ==='Mozilla Firefox' && (val ==='acconto-saldo' || val === 'partecipanti-1' || val === 'partecipanti-2' || val === 'partecipanti-3' || val === 'partecipanti-4' || val === 'partecipanti-5'))